# How can I normalize UV unwrap in blender?

Tags: uv

[image]

This picture is the UV unwrap in Maya.
Using a function called "normalize",
I spread the cylinder uv into a square shape.

I think there's a way in Blender, too.
Can you tell me how to do it?

here is my blender unwrap

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open a UV editor.  Select all verts in it.  Look on the UV menu for the UV editor, for a toggleable option called "constrain to image bounds."  Now hit s to scale, drag your mouse, and see what happens.  It won't go out of the 0,1 range for the UV editor.  Mouse click to confirm.

Comment: Or you use _Cylinder Projection_ for unwrapping and select the option _Scale to Bounds_ (if the UVs are not already scaled to bounds).

Comment: ...and the _Pivot Point_ should be set to _2D Cursor_ if the UV map is like shown in the screenshot, or else hitting S won't scale anything since the map already hits the bounds on the left and right. This way you can only scale smaller.